# Write error in prolog

Tags: prolog

My program(in SWI-Prolog) :

```
has_ram('one-v',512-mb-ram).         
has_ram('one-s',1-gb-ram).      
has_ram('m8',2-gb-ram).      
has_ram('one-sv',1-gb-ram).     
has_processor('one-v',1-ghz).    
has_processor('one-s',1.5-ghz).    
has_processor('one-m8',2.3-ghz).    
has_processor('one-sv',1.2-ghz).    
has_brand('one-v',htc).    
has_brand('one-s',htc).    
has_brand('m8',htc).    
has_brand('one-sv',htc).    
get_phone_details(X):-    
has_brand(X,Y),    
has_ram(X,Z),    
has_processor(X,P),    
write("Name   :",X),nl,    
write("Brand  :",Y),nl,    
write("Ram    :",Z),nl,    
write("Processor :",P).
```

ERROR Which i got :

```
ERROR: write/2: Domain error: `stream_or_alias' expected, found `[78,97,109,101,32,32,32,58]'
```

I would like to get the details of the phone as output.

Comment: Instead of `write("Name   :",X)` write `write('Name':X)`

Answer (score 2):

write/1 doesn't work like that, you can write :

```
write('Name      ':X),nl,    
write('Brand     ':Y),nl,    
write('Ram       ':Z),nl,    
write('Processor ':P).
```

Comment: Thank you for your  help :) .But it's showing an error (ERROR: write/2: stream `Name   ' does not exist).

Comment: I think you made a typo, did you type exactly what I wrote **write('Name    ':X), nl,**, it is ':' not ','.